# Update a model from within another model's controller using a partial view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model called `contacts` that contains a partial view for another model called `phones`. Inside the controller for `phones` I have:

```
     public PartialViewResult phonecreate()
    {
        ViewBag.PossibleUsers = context.users;
        ViewBag.PossibleContacts = context.contacts;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Now in my contacts `edit.cshtml` page I call `phonecreate()` like this:

```
    @Html.Action("phonecreate", "phones")
```

Which displays the `edit.cshtml` page of `phones` inside of the `edit.cshtml` page of `contacts`. My question is how can I actually update the phones model inside of the contacts page by filling out that partial view. I have tried `UpdateModel` but I don't think that is the right thing to do. Oh and in case this helps here is the `_CreateOrEdit` page for phones.

```
    @model Soccer.Models.phones

    @* This partial view defines form fields that will appear when creating and editing entities *@

    <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.type)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.type)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.type)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone)
    </div>
```

Is there any way I can update it from this partial view. Also If it will help I can post a screen shot of what it looks like. Thank you in advance

Comment: Create a controller action that takes a 'phones' object and use that to update your database. Let your form link to this method and you're done.

Comment: Something like this?

        public ActionResult takeIn(phones phone)
        {

            return View();
        }

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to write the data from the `phone` argument to your database. Afterwards you can return it to a list of all phones (`return RedirectToAction("Index");`.

Comment: @jeroenVannevel Ok So link the partial view to this function and that should work?

Comment: Make sure your form in the partialview is targetting that function `@using(Html.BeginForm("TakeIn", "Phones"))` and it should work, yes.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Ok I'll try it out :D

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` then any forms in that child action should post somewhere else.

If you want to do a postback (post to the same page), then you should create a view model that wraps the page's model and the what is currently the child action's model, use that view model for the page, and then just use `Html.Partial` or `Html.RenderPartial`.